# When user select 2 then two select box and input field will show and when 3 is selected then ONLY three select box and input fields is show

Tags: jquery

Here is Html code for selection of number from drop down.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#qty").click(function() {
    var selVal = $(this).val();
    if (selVal > 0) {
      for (var i = 1; i <= selVal; i++) {
        $('#piece').append('<div class="form-group" ><input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" /></div>');
        $('#sell').append('<div class="form-group"><select class="form-control" id=""><option value="">Choose Product</option><option value="Frag">Fragrance 7 in 1</option><option value="Daily">Silver Glory 200gm</option></select></div>');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label style="color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold;">Product Types</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="qty">
    <option value="">Select No of Product</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Its appending in previously selected no from drop down , and i need solution that what no should i choose it show only those no of drop down and input field

Comment: Use `change` instead of `click`.

Answer (score 2):

First I would use `.change` event and not `.click`.

Second you need to clear the html (#piece & #sell) before running your `for` loop, else they will contain the inputs from the previous selectors.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#qty").change(function() {
    var selVal = $(this).val();
    if (selVal > 0) {
    $('#piece, #sell').html("");
      for (var i = 1; i <= selVal; i++) {
        $('#piece').append('<div class="form-group" ><input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" /></div>');
        $('#sell').append('<div class="form-group"><select class="form-control" id=""><option value="">Choose Product</option><option value="Frag">Fragrance 7 in 1</option><option value="Daily">Silver Glory 200gm</option></select></div>');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#qty").change(function() {
    var selVal = $(this).val();
    if (selVal > 0) {
    $('#piece, #sell').html("");
      for (var i = 1; i <= selVal; i++) {
        $('#piece').append('<div class="form-group" ><input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" /></div>');
        $('#sell').append('<div class="form-group"><select class="form-control" id=""><option value="">Choose Product</option><option value="Frag">Fragrance 7 in 1</option><option value="Daily">Silver Glory 200gm</option></select></div>');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label style="color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold;">Product Types</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="qty">
    <option value="">Select No of Product</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="piece"></div>
<div id="sell"></div>
```

**Demo2** does not clear `#piece or #sell`, but only removes those that should not be there.

**Demo2**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#qty").change(function() {
    var selVal = $(this).val();
    var existVal = $('#piece .form-group').length;
    if (selVal > 0) {
      if (existVal > selVal) {
        $('#piece .form-group:gt(' + (selVal - 1) + ')').remove()
        $('#sell .form-group:gt(' + (selVal - 1) + ')').remove()
      } else {
        for (var i = existVal; i < selVal; i++) {
          $('#piece').append('<div class="form-group" ><input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" /></div>');
          $('#sell').append('<div class="form-group"><select class="form-control" id=""><option value="">Choose Product</option><option value="Frag">Fragrance 7 in 1</option><option value="Daily">Silver Glory 200gm</option></select></div>');
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label style="color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold;">Product Types</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="qty">
    <option value="">Select No of Product</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="piece"></div>
<div id="sell"></div>
```